# Dealing with phi function property

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, totient-function

> If $n=2^kN$, where $N$ is odd, then
>   $$\sum_{d\mid n}(-1)^{n/d}\phi(d)=\sum_{d\mid 2^{k-1}N}\phi(d)-\sum_{d\mid N}\phi(2^kd)$$

I have no idea how to seperate things inside the left side. In a nornal sum function it would be easy but any attempt to deal with this one getting me to a false solution.
the solution should be zero.

Comment: You should add how you attempted to solve this problem. Also how did you stumble on this? What are you stuck on?

Comment: @Arbuja i edited.

Comment: That good. I think the other users want you to type out your mathematical steps....but I am fine with this.

Answer (score 1):

For  $d$ dividing $n=2^{k-1}N$, then $n/d$ is even, so that's the first part of the right hand side.

For $d$ not dividing $2^{k-1}N$ but still dividing, $2^{k}N$, then $2^k$ divides $d$, and more specifically, $d = 2^kd'$ for some $d'$ dividing $N$.  In that case, $n/d$ divides $N$, which is odd, so $n/d$ is odd.  That gives you the second part of the right hand side.